# Distance to points on a cube and calculating a plane given a normal and a position

Tags: c++, math, 3d, geometry

I have two questions that have been very lacking in answers on Google.

---

**My first question - generating planes**

I am trying to calculate the 4 vertices for a finite plane based on a provided normal, a position, and a radius. How can I do this? An example of some pseudo-code or a description of an algorithm to produce the 4 vertices of a finite plane would be much appreciated.

Furthermore, it would be useful to know how to rotate a plane with an arbitrary normal to align with another plane, such that their normals are the same, and their vertices are aligned.

---

**My second question - distance to points on a cube**

How do I calculate the distance to a point on the surface of a cube, given a vector from the centre of the cube?

This is quite hard to explain, and so my google searches on this have been hard to phrase well.

Basically, I have a cube with side length `s`. I have a vector from the centre of the cube `v`, and I want to know the distance from the centre of the cube to the point on the surface that that vector points to. Is there a generalised formula that can tell me this distance?

---

An answer to either of these would be appreciated, but a solution to the cube distance problem is the one that would be more convenient at this moment.

Thanks.

**Edit:**

I say "finite plane", what I mean is a quad. Forgive me for bad terminology, but I prefer to call it a plane, because I am calculating the quad based on a plane. The quad's vertices are just 4 points on the surface of the plane.

Comment: What is a finite plane, and what are its vertices?

Comment: well, it is a quad, really. The vertices are the 4 corners. I call it a plane, because I need to calculate this quad in the same way to how you would calculate a plane.

Comment: For the second part, given a point a distance s/2 above a plane, and a vector, can you calculate the distance from the point to the plane along that vector?

Comment: A *quad?* You mean a quadrilateral? Or a square?

Comment: I mean a quadrilateral. It can be a square, but doesn't have to.

Comment: Can you formulate your question mathematically?

Comment: The given information (normal vector, location (of one vertex?) and radius (of the circumscribing circle?)) are not enough to determine the locations of the vertices of a quadrilateral. Or even of a square, for that matter.

Comment: Two different questions must be in two separated topics

Answer (score 2):

Second Question:

Say your vector is `v=(x,y,z)`

So the point where it hits the cube surface is the point where the largest coordinate in absolute value equals s, or mathematically:

`(x,y,z) * (s/m)`

where

`m = max{ |x| , |y| , |z| }`

The distance is:

`|| (x,y,z) * (s/m) || = sqrt(x^2 + y^2 + z^2) * (s/max{ |x| , |y| , |z| })`

We can also formulate the answer in norms:

`distance = s * ||v||_2 / ||v||_inf`

(These are the `l2` norm and the `l-infinity` norm)

Comment: Umm, no that isn't right. Simple counter-example: v = (1,0,0) and s = 4.

Comment: Didn't see that the cube size isn't 1. Changing 1 to s...

Comment: Okay, surely you could do the calculation on a unit cube with the same vector, the scale then result by the scale of the actual cube?

Comment: One more correction, it's maximum on absolute values